# Ansbile: merge nested list / dictionary structure

Tags: ansible

I'd like to merge a simple list / array into a nested dictionary (correct me if one of those terms is wrong)

**Playbook**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - simple:
      - right
      - middle
      - top
    - nested:
      - hostname: foo
        path:
          - left
      - hostname: bar
        path:
          - blue
          - green
          - yellow
          - "{{ simple }}"

  tasks:
    - name: content of nested
      debug:
        msg: "{{ nested }}"
```

The actual **output** is:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [content of nested] *******************************************************
Wednesday 31 August 2016  08:55:13 +0200 (0:00:00.025)       0:00:00.025 ****** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "hostname": "foo", 
            "path": [
                "left"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "hostname": "bar", 
            "path": [
                "blue", 
                "green", 
                "yellow", 
                [
                    "right", 
                    "middle", 
                    "top"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

What I'd **like to have** is (output manipulated)

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [content of nested] *******************************************************
Wednesday 31 August 2016  08:55:13 +0200 (0:00:00.025)       0:00:00.025 ****** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "hostname": "foo", 
            "path": [
                "left"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "hostname": "bar", 
            "path": [
                "blue", 
                "green", 
                "yellow", 
                "right", 
                "middle", 
                "top"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Thank you for your ideas!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing in this example would probably be (I'm not sure about the idea behind defining variables this way):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - simple1:
      - blue
      - green
      - yellow
    - simple2:
      - right
      - middle
      - top
    - nested:
      - hostname: foo
        path:
          - left
      - hostname: bar
        path: "{{ simple1 + simple 2 }}"

  tasks:
    - name: content of nested
      debug:
        msg: "{{ nested }}"
```

Comment: This is quite usefull and would solve the problem itself.

Is there a way to avoid using the helper variable simple1? I'd like to keep _blue_ _yellow_ _green_ right on the **path** under **nested**.

Comment: As a compromise, you could go `path: "{{ [ 'blue', 'green', 'yellow' ] + simple }}"`. The "nice" YAML format will not cut it with this approach. (I cannot think of anything more clever off the top of my head either.)